# Explorer.exe restart loop when log in

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, crash

I'm using Windows 8.1 Update 1, and this morning I tried to install StartIsBack, I launched the setup and clicked Install, then it restarted the explorer as I expected but explorer.exe entered into a restart loop, I mean it starts and 1 seconds after it stops and then restarts, indefinitely, without any error message.
I tried to do a SFC /ScanNow, nothing changed. The problem isn't present in Safe Mode.
Thanks

**EDIT:** I managed to start cmd.exe, and apparently explorer starts without any problem if I run it as admin, so as a temporary solution, I went in the file properties and checked "Run this program as admin".

**EDIT 2:** After around 30min of use, I've noticed that explorer.exe stops after 5/10 min.

Comment: Try [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) instead ;)

Comment: I think you didn't understand, I launched StartIsBack setup, clicked install, then the setup window closed and the explorer started to do strange stuff. Now, StartIsBack is definetely not present anymore on my computer, I uninstalled it and deleted all stuff related, but the explorer still doesn't work if started normally.

Comment: It sounds like your user profile is messed up. Try creating a new one.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to mark it as solved. Instead please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by uninstalling StartIsBack+.
In fact it was still installed but not present in Windows program list, so I used CCleaner.

Comment: report this issue to the developer: https://muut.com/startisback