# Explorer.exe crash frequent

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, crash

Some days after I solved my [precedent question](https://superuser.com/questions/933785/explorer-exe-restart-loop-when-log-in), Windows Explorer started to crash again, but now I can login and everything, but it crashes randomly (frequency vary between 40 seconds and 5 minutes) then restarts.
In the event log it looks like this (french, sorry) :

```
Récipient d’erreurs 94698196342, type 5
Nom d’événement : AutoVerifierV2
Réponse : Non disponible
ID de CAB : 0

Signature du problème : 
P1 : explorer.exe
P2 : 6.3.9600.17667
P3 : 54c6f7c2
P4 : verifier.dll
P5 : 6.3.9600.17415
P6 : 5450558e
P7 : 80000003
P8 : 000000000000b370
P9 : 201
P10 : unknown

Fichiers joints :
C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\WEREED2.tmp.appcompat.txt
C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\WEREED3.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_explorer.exe_8ae7d52bd569dec2be689810bbeb63210391320_60efbd23_cab_0d52eef0\memory.hdmp
C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_explorer.exe_8ae7d52bd569dec2be689810bbeb63210391320_60efbd23_cab_0d52eef0\triagedump.dmp

Ces fichiers sont peut-être disponibles ici :
C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_explorer.exe_8ae7d52bd569dec2be689810bbeb63210391320_60efbd23_0d531890

Symbole d’analyse : 
Nouvelle recherche de la solution : 0
ID de rapport : f3e7f08a-21d9-11e5-bf6a-ac220b896b58
Statut du rapport : 0
Récipient avec hachage : 8e1b418700b244357727dee3e46dd0eb
```

So as you can see, the problem comes from verifier.dll, which seems to be the "`Standard application verifier provider dll`". I have verified, it is the original file, it is numerically signed.
I really don't know what causes this problem...
I also tried to use Procdump to get some dump, but it doesn't get anything. I also tried modifying the registry values to enable dump creating, I set the dump folder and type etc but I didn't get anything.

Please help me :(

**EDIT:** I ran a SFC /scannow, but it didn't find any corrupted file.

**EDIT 2:** magicandre1981, I really don't know if it's related but yesterday I shut down my computer (instead of hibernate, though I have already tried to reboot) and then today I boot it, I download your .reg file and launch it, and now it's been 15 min without crash and now my Windows Search works (I was having problem with it too). I think I'm gonna wait a bit to see if it crashes again and then I will mark the problem solved. So, Thanks very much!

Comment: [Run an SFC on the PC](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: [See this page](https://startpage.com/do/search?query=explorer+crashes+windows+8.1&cat=web&pl=chrome&language=english)

Comment: run my .reg file to disable app verifer and ump creation: http://cid-128fc518635be2dc.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/MS%20Foren/Registry/WER%5E_Explorer_full_uninstall.reg Zip and upload the created Dump files, so that I can debug them.

Comment: @magicandre1981 it would appear that zdimension believes you have fixed their problem so posting an answer might be in order

Comment: but you should also share the dmp file so that I can see what causes the crash ;)

Comment: As I said, no dmp file has ever been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `verifier.dll` indicates that you have enabled [Application Verifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for Explorer.exe.

To solve this, disable Application verifier again, by deleting the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\explorer.exe` which can be done with this [.reg file from my OneDrive](http://cid-128fc518635be2dc.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/MS%20Foren/Registry/WER%5E_Explorer_full_uninstall.reg).

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly caused by third party shell extensions.

You can view all currently loaded shell extensions with this tool:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html

You should note all non Windows/Microsoft shell extensions and try disabling them 1 at a time until you find the culprit.